# How to make a div tag span the height of the page

Tags: html, css, viewport

I don't know how to ask this so pardon me if I am unclear and please ask me to clarify. I want to center a page and have a "side bar" on the right within the centered content, not the right of the viewport. This is pretty simple except I want the element to be as tall as the viewport. However, if the body tag is taller, I want it to be as tall as the body tag. I need this because the sidebar has a background that must repeat along the y-axis to cover the entire viewport. I probably didn't explain anything so perhaps this jsFiddle will clear up any missed details.

http://jsfiddle.net/dHerb/

I can set the `.center` style to have a position value of static which works but then the absolute positioning is thrown off. I could float the sidebar to the right but the height won't fill the page. I could use JavaScript, but JavaScript shouldn't be relied on for layout especially since the element that depends on it is a quarter of the page's content.

Any pointer will be much appreciated.

EDIT: Changing the body and html tag to have a height of 100% helps but it still doesn't quite behave as I described. If there is content out of the viewport and you scroll to that content, the background won't repeat.

Comment: can you draw a simple wire frame sketch. the one thing you need to do a research on is [css display] and [css position]; span have display:inline where as div has display:block, with position you make a relative to container element. please send some picture,

Comment: This has nothing to do with `span` tags. Did you look at the jsFiddle? Did I explain everything that I need to?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put everything inside of a container div.  So, for example:

```
<div id="container" style="width:960px;">
    <div id="content" style="width:800px; height:100%; float:left;">
            Your Content
    </div>
    <div id="sidebar" style="width:160px; height:100%; float:left;">
            Your sidebar
    </div>
</div>
```

Note:  I used inline style elements here for clarity in the sample code, place them in your external style sheet.

This will cause the content and the sidebar to always match the full height of the page.  If you need to, you can manually set the height of the container div and everything should size automatically.

I believe this is what you were asking, please let me know if I went down the wrong path!

Comment: In this example, the height of `#container` depends on the greater of the heights of `#content` and `#sidebar` since I have to absolutely position the `#container`.

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend using the following CSS:

```
.overlay {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 999;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}
```

The HTML part would be:

```
<div class="overlay">
    Add some content over here if you want to display something like a popup
</div>
```

I used the above code to display an overlay with a popup in it.
Why I did not use **height : 100%** is because after using that, the overlay was not showing in a specific case where the height of parent div was not specified. [Refer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7049875/why-doesnt-height-100-work-to-expand-divs-to-the-screen-height).

Comment: That definitely works, but I don't think that the `vh` unit didn't exist at the time that I posted the question. Thank you for sharing a more modern solution.

Comment: Thank you for upvoting the answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

This is a problem that CSS 2 is not equipped to handle, sadly. The standard solution people use is to make the background of the sidebar a background image on the container, but that's not really very elegant.

The only clean solution comes in the form of the magical [flexbox](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-flexbox/). Here's how to use it:

http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201103/the_css3_flexible_box_layout_flexbox/

You can find many other tutorials via The Googles.

Answer (score 1):

This might be close to what you want.

I used `display:inline-block;`

**HTML**

```
<div id="stretched">I span from the left viewport to the right viewport.</div>

<div id="main" class="center">

    <div id="left">Some text</div>

    <div id="right">I want to be on the right side of the centered content but as tall as the taller between the body tag and the viewport.</div>


</div>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
    padding: 0;
}
#stretched {
    background-color: #ddd;
    width: 100%;
}
.center {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 300px;
    height:800px;
}
#main {
    background-color: #bbb;
}
#right {
    background-color: #999;
    width: 100px;
    display:inline-block;
    height:100%;
}
#left {
    width: 195px;
    display:inline-block;
    height:100%;
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/dHerb/3/

Comment: I though about doing that but the only thing is that the stylesheet is site-wide so the length of the content in the #left and #right elements is unknown. Plus, what happens if the available height is greater than 800px? It still won't fill the viewport.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't use flexbox you can set the container's display to `inline`. See http://codepen.io/tommymarshall/pen/cECyH for demo.