# Why doesn't height: 100% work to expand divs to the screen height?

Tags: html, css, height

I want the carousel DIV (s7) to expand to the height of the entire screen. I haven't an idea as to why it's not succeeding. To see the page you can go [here](http://roseannebarr.tumblr.com).

```css
body {
  height: 100%;
  color: #FFF;
  font: normal 28px/28px'HelveticaWorldRegular', Helvetica, Arial, Sans-Serif;
  background: #222 url('') no-repeat center center fixed;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-size: cover;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.holder {
  height: 100%;
  margin: auto;
}
#s7 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%: margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 1;
}
#s7 #posts {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 13px;
  text-align: left;
  line-height: 16px;
  margin: auto;
  background: #AAA;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav">
  <a class="prev2" id="prev2" href="#">
    <img src="http://static.tumblr.com/ux4v5bf/ASslogxz4/left.png">
  </a>
  <a class="next2" id="next2" href="#">
    <img src="http://static.tumblr.com/ux4v5bf/swslogxmg/right.png">
  </a>
</div>

<div class="holder">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div id="s7">
        {block:Posts}
        <div id="posts">
```

Comment: Here's a simple and clear explanation: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31728799/3597276

Comment: probably best solution for nested elements that should not stretch to entire window's height 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7049875/height-100-not-working/17198266#17198266

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Percentage Height HTML 5/CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1622027/percentage-height-html-5-css)

Comment: Am I the only one that notices the css posted is not valid?

height: 100%: margin: auto; is not valid. The colon after 100% should be a semi-colon.

Regardless, yes, for a percentage to work, it needs to know what it is a percentage of. I would use viewport heights. Like 100vh;

Comment: In Tailwind you can set `h-screen`, which means in css `height: 100vh;`

Answer (score 579, accepted):

In order for a percentage value to work for height, the parent's height must be determined. The only exception is the **root** element `<html>`, which can be a percentage height. .

So, you've given all of your elements height, except for the `<html>`, so what you should do is add this:

```
html {
    height: 100%;
}
```

And your code should work fine.

```css
* { padding: 0; margin: 0; }
html, body, #fullheight {
    min-height: 100% !important;
    height: 100%;
}
#fullheight {
    width: 250px;
    background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id=fullheight>
  Lorem Ipsum        
</div>
```

**[JsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/MadaraUchiha/KfjGU/)**.

Comment: Ok, so this might make me look incredibly stupid, but _whatever_: Do you mean to say that `<html>` is an _actual_ element - just like `<p>` or `<img />`? I thought the only purpose of `<html>` was to define the beginning and end of an HTML document. I mean, I thought that it was there, not for layout, but just so the browser knows whar type of document it is looking at? I am completely mind-blown.

Comment: @Joey: HTML *is* an actual element. You can style it with CSS, hook events to it in JavaScript, add classes and IDs to it, and it appears in the DOM. The browser will assume an HTML document even without the `<html>` tag, and even without the `<head>` or `<body>` elements. HTML specs however, deem the `<html>` tag mandatory. In short, yes, it is a full-fledged element like all other HTML elements.

Comment: @SecondRikudo: No, the `<html>` tag is optional according to the specs (e.g. HTML4 and HTML5). And yes, the element is created anyway.

Comment: @Robert is correct; the `<html>` start and end tags are only required in XHTML, where you have to specify all the things.

Comment: hmmm... for me, the only way this worked was to set both `html` and `body` as `height: 100%` (As well as of course the specific `div` I want to inherit the 100% height)

Comment: @james Yes, all parents must have a known height.

Comment: This has saved me from desperation.

Comment: To clear up some confusion: the _markup_ for `<html>`, `<head>`, and `<body>` are optional in an HTML file, but the _elements_ will always get built. When a DOM gets constructed, by definition there will _always_ be an `html`, `head`, and `body` element, which also by definition are always ordered as `html[head,body]`. As such, even if you don't write any _markup_ using `<html> ...</html>`, any CSS or JS you write involving the `html` _element_ will work because the element is guaranteed to exist in your DOM.

Comment: @Madara'sGhost Source?

Answer (score 223):

<sub>Since nobody has mentioned this..</sub>

### Modern Approach:

As an alternative to setting both the `html`/`body` element's heights to `100%`, you could also use viewport-percentage lengths:

> [**5.1.2. Viewport-percentage lengths: the ‘vw’, ‘vh’, ‘vmin’, ‘vmax’ units**](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#viewport-relative-lengths)
>
> The viewport-percentage lengths are relative to the size of the initial containing block. When the height or width of the initial containing block is changed, they are scaled accordingly.

In this instance, you could use the value `100vh` (which is the height of the viewport) - [**(example)**](http://jsfiddle.net/dkdsfddz/)

```
body {
    height: 100vh;
}
```

Setting a `min-height` also works. [**(example)**](http://jsfiddle.net/1osg8Ler/)

```
body {
    min-height: 100vh;
}
```

These units are supported in most modern browsers - [support can be found here](http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units).

Comment: I don't see any benefit to this at all. Doesn't it create extra work for the browser which needs to calculate everything related to the browser viewport? Viewport sizing only seems beneficial when you want to actually size something related to the browser height.

Comment: @RobertWent There are benefits. For instance, `height: 100%` only works if the parent element has a defined height. There are certainly some cases where an element's parent doesn't have a defined height and viewport percentage units resolve that. In other words, if you had a deeply nested element, you could simply set `100vh`, and it would have a height of `100%` of the browser. *You* may not see any benefits, but I have been in numerous cases where they were the only solution. These units may not be as beneficial for root elements such as `html`/`body`, but nonetheless, this is an alternative

Comment: But we are talking about the body element, not a deeply nested element. There is only one possible parent, the html element. This is why I mentioned that I see no benefit and it is possibly worse than just setting 100%. Your comment says nothing to make me thin otherwise. Just because something is new doesn't make it better. It is however, an alternative.

Comment: Definition of `viewport-percentage lengths` is misleading. For real, it is just  size of viewport i.e. browser's window in most cases.

Comment: An issue with this approach is that iPhones excludes the address bar and bottom navigation from the view height, which means `body { height: 100vh }` will have a scroll bar on initial page load.

Comment: Nice. I tried the other approach, I put `height: 100% !important" to each parent til `html` without success, I could see in the dom that every node of the tree was actually `100%` but I couldn't manage to set the 100% in the desired element, but with the viewport style was easy

Comment: This answer saved my hell lot of time, thank you so much.

Comment: This is the perfect answer!

Comment: I used the "height:100vh" only on element and it works great. only solution that works.ty

Comment: Unfortunately `height:100vh` breaks on Safari

Comment: This solution creates a scrollbar on mobile, unfortunately making the old approach necessary.

Comment: the min-height fixed the issue for me

Answer (score 30):

You will also need to set 100% height on the `html` element:

```
html { height:100%; }
```

Answer (score 29):

Alternatively, if you use `position: absolute` then `height: 100%` will work just fine.

Comment: Would be a great fix if I weren't using flexbox to create my layout. :/

Comment: Don't forget to set `width:100%;` and the parent `position:relative;`.

Answer (score 11):

You should try with the parent elements;

```
html, body, form, main {
    height: 100%;
}
```

Then this will be enough :

```
#s7 {
   height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

if you want, for example, a left column (height 100%) and the content (height auto)
you can use absolute :

```
#left_column {
    float:left;
    position: absolute;
    max-height:100%;
    height:auto !important;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;

    width : 180px; /* for example */
}

#left_column div {
    height: 2000px;
}

#right_column {
    float:left;
    height:100%;
    margin-left : 180px; /* left column's width */
}
```

in html :

```
  <div id="content">
      <div id="left_column">
        my navigation content
        <div></div>
      </div>

      <div id="right_column">
        my content
      </div>
   </div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Just use this in your `css`

```css
html, body {
   height: 100%;
}
```

You'll be able to see **100% height** for all **sub classes**.

Answer (score 2):

In the page source I see the following:

```
<div class="holder"> 
    <div id="s7" style="position: relative; width: 1366px; height: 474px; overflow: hidden;">
```

If you put the height value in the tag, it will use this instead of the height defined in the css file.

Comment: That's odd because this is what I see in the page source :<div class="holder">
    <tr><td>
        <div id="s7">
            
            <div id="posts">

Comment: Ok, while I don't know how you got your above code, I went in and changed <div id="s7"> to <div id="s7" style="height:100%;"> and it worked. Perhaps it's hiding something from me? Either way thankyou :)

Answer (score 2):

If you absolutely position the elements inside the div, you can set the padding top and bottom to 50%.

So something like this:

```
#s7 {
    position: relative;
    width:100%;
    padding: 50% 0;
    margin:auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index:1;
}
```

Comment: I don't see how this could work since the 50% is relative to the width not the height of the containing element, or am I missing something here?

Answer (score 2):

Here's another solution for people who don't want to use `html, body, .blah { height: 100% }`.

```css
.app {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.full-height {
  height: 100%;
}

.test {
  width: 10px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="app">
  <div class="full-height test">
  </div>
  Scroll works too
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This may not be ideal but you can allways do it with javascript.
Or in my case jQuery

```
<script>
var newheight = $('.innerdiv').css('height');
$('.mainwrapper').css('height', newheight);
</script>
```

Comment: Never a good idea to use javascript when css alone will suffice.

Comment: Why even do something like this and complicate it more than it should be? I don't understand some answers lol...

Answer (score 0):

Try to play around also with the `calc` and `overflow` functions

```
.myClassName {
    overflow: auto;
    height: calc(100% - 1.5em);
}
```