# Make DIV 100% stretch in height inside another DIV 100% height

Tags: html, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [height:100%; not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7049875/height100-not-working)

I have two divs, one inside another. Both are set to 100% in height. Container (A) is sized properly and fills its parent but its child (B) is not being stretched to its height. When I set container (A) height in pixels, e.g. 500px, its child (B) stretches properly.

But I need container (A) to be set in percents, not pixels.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It really helps to have a sample jsFiddle for us to play with/understand you

Answer (score 1):

`height:100%`, or any percentage value, only works if the parent has an height set too.

So, in your case, the parent of div A can be either another element or the body. If that's the case, add this rule:

```
html, body { height:100%; }
```

to your CSS. Then it will work.