# iOS UIWebView You tube Video thumbnail not resize on orientation changes in objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I am using this code for loading video in `UIWebView`:

```
youTubeVideoHTML = @"<html><head>\
<body style=\"margin:0\">\
<embed id=\"yt\" src=\"%@\" type=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\" \
width=\"%0.0f\" height=\"%0.0f\"></embed>\
</body></html>";

videoWebView.delegate = self;
// Populate HTML with the URL and requested frame size
NSString *html = [NSString stringWithFormat:youTubeVideoHTML, videoURL, videoWebView.frame.size.width, videoWebView.frame.size.height];

// Load the html into the webview
[videoWebView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:nil];
[self.view addSubview:videoWebView];
```

It works fine, but on orientation change, it shows same width and height that in previous orientation.

If I use this code:

```
NSString *html = [NSString stringWithFormat:youTubeVideoHTML, videoURL, videoWebView.frame.size.width, videoWebView.frame.size.height];

// Load the html into the webview
[videoWebView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:nil];
```

in `willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation` then video stops playing and reloads the URL.

Is there any way to resize the video without reloading the page?

Comment: I got my problem I am giving width and height in pixel

Answer (score 0):

It may be because you don't have the body/html size defined so the percent doesn't know what to adjust to. See this post for more details:

[height: 100% not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7049875/height100-not-working)

Comment: Thnaks, 
I got my problem I am giving width and height in pixel.