# One div not responding to CSS after HTML/PHP change

Tags: php, html, css

Hey guys this is a very frustrating problem i have here  - right now my page works amazingly in HTML but after i change the extension to .PHP i have one div that does not react to its CSS

I had the css in a separate class just like the others and also didnt work now i have tried to specify parameters inline using style="" but that also does not work? some of them do but specifically the height percentage does not work at all! [HERE](http://www.designcorp.co.za/mock/responsivedesign/contact.php) is a live link of the php page

and here is my code for the div -

```
<div style="height:70.4%; color:#31859C;font-size:18px;font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;    padding-left: 25px; padding-right: 0px; background-color: #16334B;" id="LayoutDiv6"></div>
```

Now this pesky div does not respond to the height variable of 70.4 percent at all if i change the page to an PHP page which is imperative because it is the contact form page and i have php that needs to execute.

Sorry if this is hard to understand - basically height is not working after extension change to php

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have a height set to the divs parent element for the div to get any height by percentage, its the only way, it has nothing to do with extentions im afraid.

```
<div style="height: 1000px">
    <div style="height: 50%">this will be 500px high</div>
</div>
```

Comment: the parent can have 100% height but then that elements parent must also have a height, and so on.....

Answer (score 0):

A relative height (e.g. 70.4%) can only be relative to something absolute. So you have to set the height of a parent element to an absolute value.

Comment: thank you - i am using the responsive grid with Dreamweaver cs6 so turns out nesting is not supported but i managed to set the background color of the "grid container" class and wrap it around that specific section - works like a charm and doesn't hurt my responsive design.

Answer (score 0):

Getting divs to expand vertically to fill their height of the parent is tricky. Setting the `height` property to a percentage will only work if the height of one of the div's parents is explicitly set (for example, using the CSS rule `html { height: 100% }` but this produces it's own layout issues). See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7049918/981208) for more info.

Divs are primarily used as container and will expand to fit their contents. Looking at the page that you linked to it seems that the only issue with the div not expanding vertically is that you end up with a white block where the background of the div's parent is showing through. If you change the background color to the same background color of the div in question, then your page should look fine.