# I want to know why the navigation div is not occupying 100% height

Tags: html, css

I have a sample page as shown below

### HTML code:

```
   <div class="container">
        <div class="header floatL width100p">
            <h2>
                Header
            </h2>
        </div>
        <div class="content floatL width100p">
            <div class="floatL width29p npv">
                <p>navigation div</p>
            </div>
            <div class="floatL width70p rtb">
                <div class="floatL width100p ql">
                    <p>
                        div one
                    </p>
                    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of        the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="floatL width100p mtbs">
                    <p>
                        div two
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="floatL width100p widdiv">
                    <div class="floatL width100p">
                        <div class="floatL width40p incont">
                            <p>
                            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the     industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s
                            </p>
                            <p>
                            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the     industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s
                            </p>
                            <p>
                            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the     industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s
                            </p>
                            <p>
                            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the     industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s
                            </p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="floatL width40p incont">
                            <p>
                            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the     industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="floatL width100p">
                        <div class="floatL width40p incont">
                            <p>
                            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the     industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s
                            </p>
                            <p>
                            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the     industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s
                            </p>
                            <p>
                            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the     industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s
                            </p>
                            <p>
                            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the     industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s
                            </p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="floatL width40p incont">
                            <p>
                            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the     industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="clear"></div>

        </div>
        <div class="footer floatL width100p">
            <h2>
                Footer
            </h2>
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
```

### The styles are:

```
       *,html{
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
        .container{
            width:960px;
            margin:20px auto;
        }
        .header h2,.footer h2{
            text-align: center;
        }
        .floatL{
            float: left;
        }
        .floatR{
            float: right;
        }
        .clear{
            clear:both;
        }
        .width100p{
            width: 100%;
        }
        .width29p{
            width: 29%;
        }
        .width70p{
            width: 70.8%;
        }
        .header,.footer,.content{
            border:1px solid;
        }
        .npv{
            border-right: 1px solid;
            height: 100%;
        }
        .ql,.mtbs{
            border-bottom: 1px solid;
        }
        .width40p{
            width: 40%;
        }

        .incont{
            margin: 4%;
            background: #ccc;
            border:1px solid red;

        }
```

I would like to know why the left navigation div is not occupying 100% height as you can see by running the above code.

Any help would be appreciated. It is urgent...

Comment: What sort of selector is `*,html`? You want to select all elements *and* html?..

Comment: possible duplicate of [height:100%; not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7049875/height100-not-working)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `css tables`

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/J5fZ5/1/)**

### CSS

```
.content
{
    display: table;
    height: 100%;
}
.npv, .rtb
{
   display: table-cell; 
}
```

Comment: it is not working in ie. Can anyone suggest me why it is not working in ie

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know more about the problem than simply fix it, this is a nice article that explains the problem and give you multiple solutions: [Fluid Width Equal Height Columns](http://css-tricks.com/fluid-width-equal-height-columns/)

Comment: can you please give me a solution in ie to my question.I have tried out all the scenarios i know

Comment: That depends on IE's version. Why you try to set the height to 100%? Because of the background color? I need more Information to help you.

Comment: On testing the above code along with .content
{
    display: table;
    height: 100%;
}
.npv, .rtb
{
   display: table-cell; 
}

the navigation div is not occupying 100% height in ie10 and below versions

I want the navigation div to occupy 100% height

Comment: It should work! display:table is supported by IE since version 8 (http://caniuse.com/css-table). I created a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xGd2L/ I'm on linux and not able to test your Problem with IE.

Comment: I got the solution. The problem was with improper usage of floats.