# How to force a div to scroll after a certain size?

Tags: html, css

**The Fiddle**

This fiddle explains the problem clearly: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r5Ltc7y7/3/) (*Edit: fixed broken fiddle.*)

**The Problem**

I have a container div that has 3 divs inside of it.
The top div and middle div are dynamic in height. The bottom div is fixed.
Once the middle div expands enough, I want it to be scrollable.

**Code Snippet**

The basic structure:

```
<div id='container'>
    <div id='top'>Top (dynamic) content</div>
    <div id='middle'>Middle (dynamic) content</div>
    <div id='bottom'>Bottom (fixed) content</div>
</div>
```

The basic CSS:

```
#container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 250px;
    padding-bottom: 100px; /* bottom div height */
}

#top {
    ???
}

#middle {
    ???
}

#bottom {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100px;
}
```

**The Question**

Is there a way to accomplish this using *just CSS*? (By *just* CSS, I mean no JavaScript.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an approach using flexboxes for the layout:

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/pgtyLq1w/)

Set the `display` of the parent `#container` element to `flex`. Since you want the element to stack vertically, set the `flex-direction` property's value to `column`. And `justify-content: space-between` is used to position the last element at the bottom when the height of the middle element decreases.

It's worth pointing out that `vh` units are used to set the height of the parent element to the [height of the viewport](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7049875/height100-not-working/28121246#28121246).

```
#container {
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
```

I also set the middles element's `flex-shrink` property to a relatively arbitrary number in order for it to shrink. Then `flex-basis: 100%` is used to force the element to fill the remaining space.

```
#middle {
    overflow-y: auto;
    flex-shrink: 50;
    flex-basis: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, set a max-height on the #container. You may also need to fiddle with the overflow property. Start by setting it to scroll.

Answer (score 0):

You could do

```
#middle {
   overflow-y: auto; /* does nothing */
height: calc(100% - 100px);
}
```

Comment: I could do that if I knew what its max height could be. Since the div above it is also dynamic, I have no way of knowing.