# Why is my height: 100% property not working?

Tags: html, css

I need this to be explained to me. I thought I understood CSS; clearly I haven't a bloody clue.

```css
body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
#contain{
    position: relative;
    width: 100%
    height: 100%;
}
#wizard{
    position: absolute;
    left: 5%;
    width:10%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: black;
}
#main{
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    left: 15%;
    border-style: dashed;
    border-color: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Demo</title>
        <script>
            //css here, removed for purpose of the question
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="contain">
            <div id="wizard">
    
            </div>
            <div id="main">
            
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is one of the most basic examples of CSS positioning, and I've used this many times before. I understand that this is "incorrect", but why? why do I only see a single red dot (the condensed, dashed border of `#main`) 15% from the left, and nothing else?

Comment: have you tried to add `html, body {height: 100%;}` ?

Comment: right! now we have somthing. So i need to declare this for every time i position? i havn't had to use this before

Comment: Not really, it depends, well at least one of the parent div has to have a fixed width, otherwise it will track all the way back to body and html tags, until it finds a defined height, in this case 100%.

Comment: possible duplicate of [height:100%; not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7049875/height100-not-working)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the height to 100% for `body` and `html`, and this will provide a reference for your other elements.

You don't need to set the height to 100% for your positioned elements, simply set the top and bottom offsets to 0.  If you want to use `height: 100%`, you may get some extra height due to the border, and you can fix that by specifying the property `box-sizing: border-box`.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body, html {
  height: 100%;
}
#contain {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
#wizard {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 5%;
  width: 10%;
  background-color: black;
}
#main {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 15%;
  right: 0;
  border-style: dashed;
  border-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="contain">
  <div id="wizard"></div>
  <div id="main"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You are inheriting 100% height from nothing - so 100% of nothing is nothing. I don't know what your desired effect is exactly but you should set a height somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

This can sometimes solve the issue:

```
width:100vw;
height:100vh;
```

Answer (score 0):

The height of your `#contain` div calculates its height from its parent elements: `html`, `body`. To rectify your height issue, explicitly set each of their heights to 100%.

The absolutely positioned `#main` div had no width, so was represented as a zero pixel point surrounded by a 3px dashed border, leaving you with a red 6px square.

This jsfiddle adds `height: 100%` to the `html` & `body`, and `width: 5%` to `#main` to make the change more clear.

http://jsfiddle.net/coreysan/49u3ygq1/4/

*Note that you were missing a semicolon on the `#contain width` property, which would also cause you some problems :)*

Answer (score -1):

Try add "display: block" to your main