# Div containers 100 percent height not working

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to have two DIVs be 100% height of their containing elements. But it always stays at 200px for some odd reason. The body element and the div #wrapper are set to 100% height, but are only 200px high.

Also, when I set `HTML {height: 100%}`, using Chrome's element inspector, the actual HTML element is set to 200px.

Mock up website: 
[CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gbNzLz)
https://1cfa12692148c3352bc30134a5ae506804775e77.googledrive.com/host/0B_5GGeR4a3S6ODlydkNFQnZHbWM/index.html

Comment: What divs do you referir?

Comment: It is not clear. make a fiddle or jsbin, or codepen.

Comment: Please be more spesific. Which DIVs, IDs, Classes?..

Comment: @fcastillo 
I'm talking about the body element and #wrapper.

Comment: @UmutD.
I'm referring to body element and div #wrapper.

Comment: Please include the relevant code within the question text -- enough for a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the issue. Links are good for providing further detail, but shouldn't be the only reference.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski
Done. 
I'm just trying to understand why the body element isn't showing as 100% width. It looks like it, but when you inspect element, it's 200px.

Comment: possible duplicate of [height:100%; not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7049875/height100-not-working)

Comment: @ChaitanyaGadkari
I actually tried that and the HTML element actually sized down to 200px!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because you have a lot of float elements  and position absolute. If you use a class like .clearfix some elements your height could be good. [Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EjYbwd)

```
.clearfix { 
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
```

And I add this class to your #content

```
<div id="content" class="clearfix"> 
   ...
</div>
<div id="footer" class="clearfix"> 
   ...
</div>
```

Comment: This increased the height significantly but #wrapper height cuts short of the footer.

Comment: Yes but only add .clearfix to your footer `<div id="footer" class="clearfix">`

Answer (score 0):

Try with making `body` and `wrapper` position as absolute and set top and bottom size to 0.

```
position: absolute;
top: 0;
bottom: 0;
height:100%;
```

Hope it will do the job.