# div background not full size, only size of text

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, background-image

I am currently making a web page (using `react.js`) and I am attempting to implement a background. I would like the background to be its full size, however it is only the size of the text inside of the div with it.
Here is the code I am currently using:
`app.js`

```
<div className="header">
    <h1 className="title">blah blah blah</h1>
    <h4 className="greeting">blah blah blah</h4>
</div>
```

`app.css`

```
.header {
    background: url("./blah.png");
    position: relative;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    outline: 0;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    color: lemonchiffon;
    height: 100%;
}
```

I have tried adjusting the `height` to `100%`, however it only makes the image slightly larger. I would also like to say that the width is correct, my only issue is with getting the height to be proper.

Comment: try: background-size: auto, auto; OR background-size: contain;

Comment: it's because you use `background-size:cover` - it means the background will be resized to be large enough to "cover" the area.  Did you also give html and body (and any other ancestors) a height when you gave your header a height

Comment: what does full size mean? the div height is the height of the text. What height do you want it to be?

Comment: `className="header"` is this react thing or should be `class="header"`

Comment: @tech_Love that did not appear to make much of a difference.

Comment: @DanielH that's a react thing

Comment: @pete I have tried to give `body` a size of `100%`.

Comment: yeah you also need to give html and any other ancestors of header a size too, if you only added it to body, the height for header definitely won't work - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7049875/height-100-not-working

Comment: @joshuamiller I would like the image to be `100%` size while keeping the proportions of the browser window and place text over the image.

Comment: @Pete `header` has no ancestors, it is the first div of the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use 100vh as viewport (100% of screen height)

> REF: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp

use the following to remove default margin from body and h1.

```
body, h1{
  margin: 0;
}
```

```css
.header {
  background: url("http://placehold.it/1920x1080");
  position: relative;
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  outline: 0;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  color: lemonchiffon;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
}

body, h1{
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <h1 className="title">blah blah blah</h1>
  <h4 className="greeting">blah blah blah</h4>
</div>
```

Comment: This helps, however the image is now far too wide and only 20% vertically of the image is shown.

Comment: @JakeOrben ok updated

Comment: That appears to have worked!

Answer (score 1):

```
html { 
  background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  background: url("./blah.png");
}
```

reference: https://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

Comment: This places the background over the entire page, not just the desired `div`.

Answer (score 0):

Target the html if you want a full page background.

```
html {
    background: url("./blah.png");
   -webkit-background-size: cover;
   -moz-background-size: cover;
   -o-background-size: cover;
   background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: .html is an css selector an class, i think that you mean html

Comment: Yes thanks for that @PatrickSampaio

Answer (score 0):

It can't be done like that, the element cannot be adjusted to the background size dynamically.

Here are some options

- Insert the image with an `<img>`-tag, place the h1 and h4 on top of it with `position: absolute`
- Adjust the header to the height of the image manually: `height: 300px`
- make the image shrink to the size of the div: `background-size: contain`

Answer (score 0):

when you want to make full background your div should also be full height
since `height:100%` relative to parent's height you should make parent also `height:100%`
one alternative is that you can use

```
body{
    background: url("./blah.png");
    position: relative;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center; //added line
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    outline: 0;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    color: lemonchiffon;
    min-height: 100%;
}
html{
    min-height:100%;
}
```

which strecth your html tag to 100% height at minimum as well as your body. If you want only make a specific element 100% height I suggest you to use `height: 100vh;` which makes div 100% relative to client screen

Answer (score 0):

Just put the background on the `body`:

```
.background {
  background: url("http://images.all-free-download.com/images/graphiclarge/black_texture_texture_background_06_hd_pictures_169901.jpg");
}

.header {
    position: relative;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    outline: 0;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    color: lemonchiffon;
    height: 100%;
}

  <body class = "background">
    <div class="header">
      <h1 class="title">blah blah blah</h1>
      <h4 class="greeting">blah blah blah</h4>
    </div>
  </body>
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/DDmWdwViw8aKI36EwOKM?p=preview