# html.fa-events-icons-ready is taking over space and messing up the body?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, font-awesome

I have a couple of questions regarding my code and its result:
[image]

- Why isn't the body height taking 100% height? You can see the background
  image is messed up because of it. Apparently there's this `html.fa-events-icons-ready`  element messing it up ?
- What's the 'ideal' initial CSS setup for the html,body ? I found this
  minimalistic template, is this considered okay for simple pages/apps?
   `html,body {
      box-sizing: border-box;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
  }`

Here's the [full code](https://codepen.io/JRuivo/full/YxmQmJ/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

100% height works funny, you need to set it on the html tag. Also the margin on the wrapper was causing the background to stretch past the height of the window.

Amend your CSS as per the below:

```
html, 
body {
  height: 100%;
}

.wrapper {
  padding: 50px;
  margin: auto;
}
```

The accepted answer in this post explains the way height works pretty well:
[height: 100% not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7049875/height-100-not-working)

Also, instead of `height:100%` you can also try the `vh` unit (view height). e.g. `height:100vh` which doesn't require setting the height on the parent element.