# Div is only as tall as content

Tags: html, css

Like I said the div is only as tall as the content. I have the div:

```
  <div class="body-container">
  <p>Hello</p>

  </div>
```

And the CSS:
    `body-container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: blue;
}`
However, the background only appears on the Hello paragraph. This is super annoying as I want the background to cover the entire page! Thanks for the help.

Comment: height:100% requires an height on parent for calculation. if it is a direct child of body, then you need also: `html , body {height:100%}` Html will use window's height , body will take 100% from html height's value and so on .body-container will use body's height  ;)  You can also use :`height:100vh` to use calculation from window's height

Comment: You wanted to write .body-container (with the dot) and not simply body-container, right?

Comment: This question already has a very good answer on SO. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7049875/height-100-not-working

Comment: @TeaCode I looked all over and couldn't find something like this! Thanks! It resolved it!

Comment: @G-Cyr Sweet! this worked, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you style a class by adding a dot before it, like `.body-container`.  
As for your problem, by setting a height and width of `100%` to the `.body-container`, `html` and `body` must also have width and height of `100%` in order for the `.body-container` to take full size, like:

```css
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.body-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="body-container">
  <p>Hello</p>

</div>
```

You can also force full size using viewport units `vh` and `vw`:

```css
.body-container {
  width: 100vw;  /* 1vw = 1% of screen width */
  height: 100vh; /* 1vh = 1% of screen height */
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="body-container">
  <p>Hello</p>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try change height property to:

```
height: 100vh;
```