# Checkbox (input) height and width changing for mobile screen sizes?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I have the following code:

```
<div class="container-fluid mt-5">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-10">
      Hello
      <br>
      Hello
    </div>
    <div class="col-2">
        <input type="checkbox" class="w-100 h-100">
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

[JS fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tjggaaks/)

This is what the checkbox looks like on desktop displays:
[image]

And this is what the checkbox looks like on mobile displays:
[image]

I don't understand why the size of the checkbox is changing for desktop displays. Should it not have the same height/width for both mobile and desktop since I am specifically setting its size using `h-100` and `w-100`?

Comment: Maybe this will help ypu. See examples https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Advanced_styling_for_HTML_forms

Comment: Why do you use `h-100` and `w-100` classes?

Answer (score 0):

The `class = 'w-100 h-100'` force them to use 100% of width and height. If you do not need this, try to set the width and height instead of using this classes.

Look the classes:

```
.h-100 {
    height: 100%!important;
}
.w-100 {
    width: 100%!important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems.

The checkbox is inside a `col-2` which is getting narrower in width. Both `height:100%` and `width:100%` are relative to the size of the parent container (`col-2`). Also, `height:100%` only works when the parent has a defined height as [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7049875/height-100-not-working) and in several other answers.

Also, the `col-2` has padding which impacts the size of the input.