# How to fix a background img that isn't showing

Tags: html, css

My background image isn't showing and I can't figure out why. I've already read through a few other threads but none of the suggestions are working.

The path to the background image is correct, that's not the problem. I've added a height and size/position etc.

```css
.images {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

#slideshow {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  background: url("links/slideshow/_anx_tote2.jpg");
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 100% bottom;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="images">
  <div id="slideshow"></div>
</div>
```

The background image should cover the right half of the screen.

Comment: Your element **has no width**.

Comment: probably is the negative z-index (and the width missing)

Comment: I've set the width to 100% and removed the z-index but it's still not showing

Comment: possible duplicate of : https://stackoverflow.com/q/1622027/8620333

Comment: works fine for me... https://jsfiddle.net/vp1hwqn3/

Comment: the problem was the width: 100%; I changed it to 100vh and it's working now! Thanks everyone

Answer (score 0):

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body,
html {
  height: 100%;
}

.images {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

#slideshow {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  background-image: url("https://picsum.photos/200");
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 100% bottom;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="images">
  <div id="slideshow"></div>
</div>
```

You need to add 100% height for body and HTML.

Answer (score 0):

The image doesn't show because there was no width and height set to `#slideshow`.

Adding percentage height to a div, a height has to be determined first. 
For more information, you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7049875/why-doesnt-height-100-work-to-expand-divs-to-the-screen-height).

Thus I have added `height: 100vh;` and `width: 100%` to `#slideshow`;

```css
.images {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

#slideshow {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  background: url("https://i.imgur.com/WLimwqR.png");
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 100% bottom;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="images">
  <div id="slideshow"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 #slideshow {
background: url(links/slideshow/_anx_tote2.jpg) no-repeat transparent;
background-size: cover;
height: 100%; 
}
```