# Image does not appear in my section if I try it to upload from css file, but it works when I try it from html

Tags: html, css

I have created a section and I named it `class="sectionOne"`. Right now this section is empty, but I try to add a background with image and it does not appear there. However, if I add a style in `<>`. For example `.section class="sectionOn" style="background: url();"` my image appears, but very small, but if I do it in css it does not appear. I have linked my html file with css, any ideas where's the problem? My path is correct 100%

[inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uyUTI.png)
[my structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J2GMX.png)

```css
.sectionOne {
    background: url(../images/kendall-henderson-Pj6TgpS_Vt4-unsplash.jpg);
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<section class="sectionOne">

</section>
```

Comment: Look in the network tab. Your styles and images dir are likely not in parallel

Comment: Is the path correct relative to your CSS file? - what is your directory structure?

Comment: i updated this post with few photos. Take a look. Also my url is now without "", tried with them  - still does not work

Comment: You have no content in your `section` so it has no reason to be anything other than 0 height. Add some content, or set a `height` with a length that's not relative (i.e., not %). See also [Why doesn't height: 100% work to expand divs to the screen height?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7049875/215552)

Comment: width: 100%; height: 100%;position: fixed; Solved my problem. Ill take a look about content in section, thanks.