# object-fit: contain is not working. The shortest dimension fills the container and the rest overflows

Tags: css

When I have a container with `max-width:80vw` and `max-height:80vh`, the image contained within it is not behaving properly in line with `object-fit:contain`. The image has `height:100%` and `width:100%` as well as `object-fit:contain` but the shortest dimension of the image fills the container with the longer dimension overflowing.

Please have a look at this url:

https://mutatedllama.pythonanywhere.com/share/7h25JNbi

Could somebody help me to understand where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 2):

[`height: 100%` only works if every ancestor element also has a defined height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7049875/why-doesnt-height-100-work-to-expand-divs-to-the-screen-height) (so implicit `height: auto;` will cause it to fail).

I was able to make it work in the page by setting an explicit `height: 100%` on `html`, `body`, `div.container`, `div.row.justify-content-center`, and `div#image-box` - this is the descendant path from `<html>` to the `<img />` - but obviously this is a bad idea.

**In short: don't use `height: 100%;`**

Instead, make the `div#image-box` a `display: flex;` with `flex-direction: column;` and give the `img` `flex-grow: 1;`.

Things are complicated by the overlay `img` sibling of the original cat picture - you may need to play with your HTML structure.

Comment: Thank you, your comment helped! Your first statement made it click for me - the parent did not have a defined height, only a max-height. When I replaced max-height and max-width with height and width it worked. Thanks!