# DIV to take the height of its parent

Tags: css, vue.js

I have following HTML which works fine. But I want the div to take the height of the tab and not having  to say its 200px. If I give 100% it does not work. Please ignore draggable as its 3rd party

```
<b-tab title="TAB">
  <div class="table-wrapper-scroll-y custom-scrollbar">
    <table class="table table-sm table-bordered table-striped table-hover">
      <draggable :list="myLoop" :options="dragOptions" :element="'tbody'" class="rows">
        <tr class="cursor-ns-resize" v-for="(row, index) in myLoop" :key="index">
          <td>
            <b-form-checkbox type="checkbox" v-model="row.checked" />
          </td>
          <td>
            <span>{{ row.label }}</span>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </draggable>
    </table>
  </div>
</b-tab>
```

CSS

```
.custom-scrollbar {
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.table-wrapper-scroll-y {
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why doesn't height: 100% work to expand divs to the screen height?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7049875/why-doesnt-height-100-work-to-expand-divs-to-the-screen-height)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you give the parent (`b-tab`) flex then the child `div` will inherit the height (as long as there's no implicit height assigned to the `div`). You will need to set the `div` to have `flex-grow` and `flex-shrink` as 1 (or combine them into the single `flex` property - `flex: 1 1`).

I've added some coloured borders to the two elements for demonstrating purposes:

```css
b-tab {
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 200px;
  display: flex;
}

.custom-scrollbar {
  position: relative;
  overflow: auto;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  flex: 1 1;
}

.table-wrapper-scroll-y {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<b-tab title="TAB">
  <div class="table-wrapper-scroll-y custom-scrollbar">
    <table class="table table-sm table-bordered table-striped table-hover">
      <draggable :list="myLoop" :options="dragOptions" :element="'tbody'" class="rows">
        <tr class="cursor-ns-resize" v-for="(row, index) in myLoop" :key="index">
          <td>
            <b-form-checkbox type="checkbox" v-model="row.checked" />
          </td>
          <td>
            <span>{{ row.label }}</span>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </draggable>
    </table>
  </div>
</b-tab>
```

Comment: I do not want to specify 200px in the tab as well. My form already has a height.

Comment: `b-tab` doesn't have a height so I had to assign one for testing. You can remove this property. The only properties you need to look at is `display:flex` on the parent and `flex: 1 1` on the children.

Comment: It still does not work. I changed overflow: scroll; on the div but then the scrollbar never comes and the tab becomes really big

Comment: I think you want to specify some max-height either on the tab or the div.

Comment: If I have to give max-height then my original code works well. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you need to add

```
*{//this effects every element
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
```

To your css most of the browsers add x margin and padding