# Page with 100% height. Nested div overflow-y dont work

Tags: html, css, flexbox

i try make 100% height page with flex.
**Then few items ,  looks like all very good**:

[image]

Then i add more items in list , div_content height out bottom browser and appearas page scroll

[image]

If i add overflow-y: scroll for item list its dont help ... how can fix this ?

[image]

**SANDBOX:** 
https://liveweave.com/9bGsqj    (press f5 after loading)

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, you just need to change **100%** to **100vh**, and the issue will be solved, usually it's happening because of different parent height properties.
[image]
[image]
Also this problem widely explained here: 
[Why doesn't height: 100% work to expand divs to the screen height?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7049875/why-doesnt-height-100-work-to-expand-divs-to-the-screen-height)

Also, try to think in relatedness way, I did not found something that really will help to understand, at least MDN explanation is not bad and with some examples
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow
[image]

Comment: then i try change % to 100vh , then i get bottom out with items and without (i think 100vh dont consider div_menu)

Comment: its hard to say why are you still have problem so, would be very helpful to see structure and full picture of what is going on, can you post to fiddle?

Comment: I see, but what about your example? i see there only <p class="lw">Hello Weaver!</p>. Edited: okay, i see its changed, one moment

Comment: its should work:   https://liveweave.com/9bGsqj     (press f5 after loading)

Comment: okay, just add "overflow-y: auto" to <div class="content"></div>, i think its because after you applied "overflow: hidden", its applied to all inner divs too

Comment: yes its work. But i dont understand how its magic work (flex+overflow), where i can read about it ?. Why need apply to "content"?.  And i try move overflow:scroll from column to itemList(without button) not work :(

Comment: Actually, this is not problem of flex, if you will "display: block" and make appropriate height, you will get same problem you just need to play with overflow: auto and overflow: hidden and try to gei it, it will take sometime, but without practice you very possibly won;t get it.So made for you some screenshot with explanation, hope it will help you understand at least idea of it, if not, ask me more)