# background image not showing up in html page

Tags: html, css, image

I'm a beginner in html and I am trying to use an image as a complete background to my page . I want the image to fit my sceen so that I do not have to scroll down to see the rest of the image. I have tried this but the image doesn't even load to begin with .

```css
.html , .body{
  margin:0;
  height:100%;
}

#map{
  background: url("HTML_FILES/IMAGES/map.jpg");
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div id = "map"></div>
```

My folder structure is like :

```
PROJECT 
  HTML_FILES
      mypage.html
      IMAGES 
          map.jpg
```

I would appreciate your help with guiding me to  load the image and adjust it correctly . Thank you in advance .

Comment: background: url("IMAGES/map.jpg"); please try this.

Comment: HTML_FILES remove path of the backgound in #map

Comment: @RayeesAC Didn't work

Comment: I give you a sample

Comment: Your div has a height of 0. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7049875/why-doesnt-height-100-work-to-expand-divs-to-the-screen-height)

Comment: make to use position:absolute; there is no height problem.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.html , .body{
  margin:0;
  height:100%;
}

#map{
  background-image: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1495567720989-cebdbdd97913?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1000&q=80);
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
}
```

```html
<div id = "map"></div>
```

Comment: Plesae check this @VASILEIOS SKENTOS

Comment: It loaded the picture . Let me test the resolution of some other pics

Comment: https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1495567720989-cebdbdd97913?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1000&q=80 please change path of this image

Comment: HTML_FILES/IMAGES/map.jpg to give this. if image path is same

Answer (score 0):

Use the below style to get it done.

```
body {
    background: url(HTML_FILES/IMAGES/map.jpg);
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
```