# If i don't hardcode <div> height component inside is hidden

Tags: reactjs, styles, expand

I like to make a `div` expand according to its content height but the hole `Component` inside that `div` is hidden if I use like `height: '100%'`. It's a bit complex and wish for some extra eyes!

I made a [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/greta100-masonry-not-expanding-with-its-content-z1ux1?file=/src/components/sections/TimeLineViewer.js)

Looks like this in Chrome:

[image]

I can see during debug that the "hidden" `Component` is rendering ok so it's strange that it's "hidden"

If I set the same `Style` to `height: 1000` the `<ul>` have Children:

[image]

But I want it to expand according to its content height so `height: 1000` will not work.

In this [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/greta100-masonry-not-expanding-with-its-content-z1ux1?file=/src/components/sections/TimeLineViewer.js) I set the `height: 1000,` to demonstrate what happens. The `Component` that refuse to expand height is a `Masonry` image gallery `Component`

```
style={{
    width,
    height: 1000,
    position: 'relative',
    margin: '0 auto',
}}
```

When you open the Sandbox you see in the left editor windows this `TimeLineViewer.js` and the `Style` code problem. The `TimeLineViewer.js` loads the `Masonry` image gallery `Component` `Masonry.js`

What I have tried is to set parent to also 100% height but with no luck.. I'm a little bit new to JavaScript and HTML so advice would be good

Comment: Your sandboxes not working coz it gives a runtime errors, seems like you just copied the code without making it work. Also you **don't** need to share all your project (too much noise), you should make a **MINIMAL** reproducible example [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: My Sandbox works maybe your laptop is slow. It's a LARG complex project and that is a minimal reproducible example considering..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To debug this, start by taking off or commenting out the `LeComponent` and then testing your `div` actual height when you are implementing the `100%` height.

```
<div
    style={{
        width,
        height: !fullscreen && "100%",
        position: fullscreen ? 'initial' : 'relative',
        margin: '0 auto',
    }}
>
    {/* <LeComponent
        infinite
        items={items}
        itemRenderer={ItemRenderer}
        gutter={gutter}
        outerGutter={outerGutter}
        extraPx={0}
        debug={debug}
        rows={{
            0: 1,
            320: 2,
            480: 3,
            640: 4,
        }}
        cols={{
            0: 1,
            360: 2,
            640: 2,
            960: 3,
            1280: 4,
            1400: 5,
            1720: 6,
            2040: 7,
            2360: 8,
        }}
        onEnd={() => {
            // TODO possible when many items lazy load them
            // this.addItems();
        }}
    /> */}
</div>
```

You will notice, that it still takes up no height at all and the component you created did not have any bearing to that. This is because it is a CSS issue. [The height percentage cannot be determined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7049875/why-doesnt-height-100-work-to-expand-divs-to-the-screen-height) because there is no parent or ancestor with a height definition. You are getting the percentage of void.

After that, we can take a glance at your `Masonry` component. Just by looking at the method identifiers (such as `_getDimensions`, `_setContainerHeight`) and further reviewing the code base, we can learn that this component is actually dependent on certain element dimensions (most likely the parent `div` dimension as well) - and from what we learned from the CSS issue awhile ago, the parent `div` actually has a `height` of 0.

At this point, I took out the `style` props on your Masonry Component so that it would not be dependent on the parent dimensions and that fixed the issue

```
<div ref={this.container}>
    <ul ref={this.list}>
        {mounted && items.map((item, index) => this.renderItem({ index, item, maxIndex }))}
    </ul>
</div>
```

[image: Edit Greta100 Masonry not expanding with it's content (forked)]

Comment: Excellent I learn so much. In 5 hour I give you the bounty

Comment: Will push your changes to the [repo](https://github.com/erikswed/Greta-100-React-Web-App). I learn Rectjs and Javascript coming from ANdroid, Java c++ ##

Comment: I'll check later. You can use the same concept from what I was talking about - the content cannot depend on the containing div's height since the containing div height is already dependent on the content's height

Comment: The vertical Masonry was broken before so has nothing to do with you Thanks