# Increase the height of a video inside a <DIV>

Tags: html, css, wordpress

although I have been able to set "style:max-width:80%" in the HTML, whenever I insert the "max-height: 100%" it is not picked up.

Below you can find the HTML code:

```html
<div style="max-width: 80%; max-height: 1000%;" class="wp-block-cover has-background-dim">
  <video class="wp-block-cover__video-background" autoplay="" muted="" loop="" playsinline="" src="https://deepbraincommerce.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/03/Home-Video.mp4" style="object-position:50% 50%"></video>
  <div class="wp-block-cover__inner-container">
    <div data-v-45c77fc7="" class="home__title">Business growth lives here.
    </div>
    <p></p>
    <div class="buttons">   
      <button type="button" class="home-button" onclick="location.href = 'https://deepbraincommerce.com/we-do/';">We Do &nbsp;&nbsp;&gt;
        <span class="btn-overlay"></span>
      </button><p></p>
      <button type="button" class="home-button" onclick="location.href = 'https://deepbraincommerce.com/portfolio/';">Succeed &nbsp;&nbsp;&gt;
        <span class="btn-overlay"></span>
      </button><p></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here the website: deepbraincommerce.com

Let me know if you need anything else, is the first time I post

Comment: Possible duplication: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7049875/why-doesnt-height-100-work-to-expand-divs-to-the-screen-height