# Div not being fully sized to 100%

Tags: html, css

My div is not being fully 100% as there is still a margin to it

output:

[image]

at the top there is still some whitespace

**CSS code:**

```
.topbar {
    width: 100%;
    height: 10%;
    background-color: black;
}
```

thanks!

Comment: Do you use a css reset? Some browser has default margins for body for example

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why doesn't height: 100% work to expand divs to the screen height?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7049875/why-doesnt-height-100-work-to-expand-divs-to-the-screen-height)

Comment: You need to reset , try this:   `* { margin: 0; padding: 0; }`

Comment: Add `html {height: 100%;}` to body
and `{margin:0; padding:0;}` to Element

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a `margin` at your body probably.

Body comes with a default margin. Try this.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

If this not work for you, try to set `margin: 0` to your other elements to find which one causing this.

Also you can use developer tools and see where comes from this margin.

Comment: Worked like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

```
html, body{
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
}
```

This may help you .

Comment: thanks! although that's a more "safe" way of being sure that the margin is gone