# Why do my pseudo element disappears after using position absolute on the parent element?

Tags: html, css

So what I want is to have a horizontal line on the right side of my `p` element, so I applied a `border-bottom: 1px solid black` to `p::after`, like this

(The elements' `outline` in `red`, `blue`, and `green` are for debugging and are not part of the final design)

```css
div {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;

    outline: 1px solid red;
}

p {
    transform: rotate(-90deg);

    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;

    outline: 1px solid blue;
}
    p::after {
        content: "";
        flex: 1 1;
        border-bottom: 1px solid black;
        margin: auto;
        margin-left: 10px;

        outline: 1px solid green;
    }
```

```html
<div>
    <p>Text here!</p>
</div>
```

The code above works fine and it achieves what I want.

...however, if I want to move the `p` tag using `position: absolute`, the line disappears (see the snippet below). How can I work around this?

```css
div {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;

    outline: 1px solid red;
}

p {
   transform: rotate(-90deg);
   display: flex;

   position: absolute;
   top: 50%;
   left: 50%;

   outline: 1px solid blue;
}
    p::after {
        content: "";
        flex: 1 1;
        border-bottom: 1px solid black;
        margin: auto;
        margin-left: 10px;

        outline: 1px solid green;
    }
```

```html
<div>
    <p>Text here!</p>
</div>
```

Comment: BTW, pseudo-elements use `::`, e.g. `div::before` and `a::after`, not `:`. A single-colon is for pseudo-classes, not pseudo-elements (though browsers do support `:after` and `:before` for now, it's deprecated syntax).

Comment: You say you want a "horizontal" line on the "right-side" of the `p`, but is that the right-side **before** or _after_ applying the `rotate(90deg)` transformation?

Comment: @Dai Oh alright thank you will edit my code accordingly using `::`. I'm rotating -90 degree so it should still be **after**.

Comment: Remember that `transform: rotate` applies to all descendant boxes too, including `::after`, so `border-bottom: 1px solid black` will result in a **vertical line**. not a horizontal one. Anyway, I don't think you need to use `transform: rotate()` at all: there are better ways of rotating text.

Comment: You also _should not_ be using `-webkit-transform` anymore, just use `transform` without the prefix. It's been standard and widely supported _without the prefix_ since 2014.

Comment: I've edited your post to add an `outline` to the boxes - which I hope should also help reveal what's going on.

Comment: I'm still confused by what you expect a "horizontal" line "on the right side" of the `<p>` should look like - please post a sample image or mock-up that shows us what you want to see.

Comment: @Dai what I'm expecting is exactly like what the snippet above shows. It's originally a horizontal line and when I rotate it, it becomes a vertical right.

Comment: @Dai The syntax is not deprecated, it's just old-standard syntax (CSS 2.1).

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your code is that:

1. You did not define the height of the outer `<div>`: while you put `height: 100%` [**that won't work**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7049875/why-doesnt-height-100-work-to-expand-divs-to-the-screen-height): it is not correct to use `height: 100%` to fill the viewport, instead use `100vh`.
2. The other problem is with `position: absolute`: I fix it defining in the rest of the sides the 0 and the left the `45%` and adjust it to suit you if you wanted to center the paragraph and line in the parent container you could have done it without the absolute position

```css
    * {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    div {
        position: relative;
        height: 100vh;
        width: 100%;
        padding-bottom: 20px;
        background-color: #2f4;
    }

    p {
        transform: rotate(-90deg);
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        width: 200px;
        align-items: center;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0%;
        left: 45%;
        bottom: 0%;
        right: 0%;
    }
        p:after {
            content: "";
            flex: 1 1;
            border-bottom: 1px solid black;
            margin: auto;
            margin-left: 10px;
        }
```

```html
<div>
    <p>Text here!</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you provide HTML code also please ?

Comment: Only have the pattern and child the other html is the structure basic