# Using height 100% of parent without explicitly defining height of parent

Tags: css

I have this very simple snippet:

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  background-color: blue;
}

.child100 {
  width: 6px;
  height: calc(100% - 5px);
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="child100"></div>
    <div class="childContent">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <th>
            1
          </th>
          <th>
            2
          </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>
            3
          </th>
          <th>
            4
          </th>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

`height: calc(100% - 5px);` doesn't take any effect, also if I set `height: 100%` for `html body and parent tags`.
I don't want to explicitly define the height of parent in pixels, rather I want it to fit its content (taking the height of table).
I don't want the position of `child100` to be absolute as the `parent` div is part of a very long element with overflow and that will stuck `child100` ontop when scrolling, rather than being next to `table`.
Also, omitting `height` attribute for `.child100` and adding `margin-bottom: -5px` for the other child will affect the height of the whole `parent` element as seen by the background-color.

Comment: remove the height definition and it will fit the height of the table by default

Comment: @TemaniAfif It's not a solution, as you can see, I need its height to be 100% - 5px and not the height of the table

Comment: add `margin-bottom: -5px;` to the other child

Comment: @TemaniAfif I edited the question, please take a look

Comment: Why don't you just add margin-bottom: 5px to `.child100` and remove the height property? Heights don't work if the size of the parent isn't specified explicitly (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7049918/12571484) answer for details)

Comment: margin-bottom: 5px to the first child then

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the height definition and add a bottom margin. The stretch alignment of flexbox will do the job for your.

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.child100 {
  width: 6px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="child100"></div>
    <div class="childContent">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <th>
            1
          </th>
          <th>
            2
          </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>
            3
          </th>
          <th>
            4
          </th>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```