# Contents in div overflowing despite div being 100% height

Tags: html, css

I am currently working on a survey form project from freecodecamp and I'm facing some issues with my CSS (I've been finding it a bit hard, so go easy on me please >.< ).

This is the html I have, abbreviated since it is a bit long (only showing the essential parts):

```html
<body>
        <div class="container">
            <h1 id="title">Survey Form</h1>
            <p id="description">Tell us how your experience was like!</p>
            <form method="post" action="" id="survey-form">
                <fieldset>
                    <label for="name-label">Name <input id="name-label" name="name" type="text" placeholder="Please enter your name"  required/></label>
                    <label for="email-label">Email <input id="email-label" name="email" type="email" placeholder="Please enter your email"  required/></label>
                    <label for="number-label">Age <input id="number-label" name="number" type="number" placeholder="Please enter your age" min="16" max="120" required/></label>       
                </fieldset>
                <fieldset>
                <legend>Would you recommend the event to a friend? (required)</legend>
                <select id="dropdown">
                    <option value="">(select an option)</option>
                    <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
                    <option value="No">No</option>
                </select>
                </fieldset>
                <fieldset>
                    <legend>Ticket Type (required)</legend>
                    <label for="normal-ticket"><input id="normal-ticket" value="normal-ticket" name="ticket-type" type="radio" checked /> Normal</label>
                    <label for="vip-ticket"><input id="vip-ticket" name="ticket-type" value="vip-ticket" type="radio" /> VIP Pass</label>
                    </fieldset>
                <fieldset>
                    <legend>What did you purchase?</legend>
                    <label for="snacks">
                        <input id="snacks" type="checkbox" value="snacks">
                    Snacks
                    </label>
                    <label for="drinks-alcoholic">
                        <input id="drinks-alcoholic" type="checkbox" value="drinks-alcoholic">
                    Drinks (alcoholic)
                    </label>
                    <label for="drinks-non-alcoholic">
                        <input id="drinks-non-alcoholic" type="checkbox" value="drinks-non-alcholic">
                    Drinks (non-alcoholic)</label>
                    <label for="food">
                        <input id="food" type="checkbox" value="food">
                    Food
                    </label>
                    <label for="merch">
                    <input id="merch" type="checkbox" value="merch">
                    Merchandise
                    </label>
                </fieldset>
                <fieldset>
                    <label>Any tips for next time? 
                        <textarea name="tips"></textarea>
                    <label>
                </fieldset>
                <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Submit"/>
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
```

And my CSS:

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: "Gill Sans", sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  background: url({base64 image url here});
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  overflow: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

div {
  width: 60%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
  display: block;
}

h1,
p {
  text-align: center;
}

form {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 60vw;
  max-width: 500px;
  min-width: 300px;
  height: 60vh;
}

fieldset {
  border: none;
}

label {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
}

input[type="submit"] {
  margin: 1em auto;
}
```

Basically, I want the div to act an opaque background for the contents, while the body's background is an image that takes up the entire screen, while the div takes up only the width specified. The problem is, the div's length is not taking up 100% of the height, despite being that on the CSS. And the form's contents is overflowing.

I was able to fix the overflow with -> {overflow: scroll} but I was wondering if there is any other way to do this? Also, why is this happening if the contents are within the div?

I tried looking up other answers, but didn't find a solution that helped yet.

**What I tried:**

I tried using `min-height` instead of `height` for the body, and then later with `html,body` but that didn't solve the issue. I also tried this with div.

Since I wanted the div to serve as a background container, I tried placing it absolute, relative to the body, but I wasn't sure how to position it properly where I wanted it (centered) and the height was still not 100%. Also, I wasn't sure if this markup would be better than having everything inside the div (does it?):

```html
<body>
  <div></div>
  {rest of the markup}
</body>
```

Edit: I added the body of the HTML as I see from the comments it might provide some more context! Sorry if it's too long, let me know and I'll remove the less important bits :D

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) using the `<>` icon.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Comment: You may want to look at the answers [to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7049875/215552) as well as [the results of this search](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+css+height+100%25+does+not+work)

Comment: Without seeing the html content (ie. codepen) I can only suggest that you may want to put overflow-y:scroll on your form instead of your div. form { overflow: scroll; }

Comment: In my experience, it is best to move the css you have written for the body to a specific div container inside the dom. Leave the body as it is as that will scroll naturally depending on the content, but if you want a fixed background, with an image with `background-size: cover` it is best to move that into it's own div. I can easily knock up an example if you like.

Comment: Hey @Iharby, thank you! I will try that out, but I would love to see an example too just for clarification :D

Comment: Also, thank you @Heretic Monkey (I'll check out those results you linked to).

I'll update if I figure it out here on end :)

Comment: Thank you @kruddock! I'll see what the scroll for the form looks like

Comment: Try use the unit `vh` instead of `%` of height for `body`? I'm sure it will make the height of body full height of screen, not sure about the div though, but you can use the same for it and use scroll if it get longer so you don't have scroll on body.

Comment: Hi @Eezo, thank you! I posted an answer below with what helped, and I made the html, body with %, while the form and div vh and vw. Does it make sense to do it this way? I found the body had some default margin to it...

Comment: Oh you don't have any kind of "reset css" which remove the default margin on body and some more? Well, for simple reset, just use `* {margin: 0; padding: 0;}` and add 'box-sizing: border-box' if needed to prevent bigger element when using padding/border.

Comment: @Eezo oh I didn't know that! I looked into box-sizing:border-box as you stated, and it makes a lot of sense to use it in this case too :D Thank you so much!!

Comment: You're welcome. Glad i can help you with some simple line of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what was causing the overflow and extra blank spaces around the div.

The body had some extra margin, apparently, that I caught when inspecting the page. So, once I set `body{margin: 0;}` the div took up `100vh`!

Also, I made only one main-container for all the items, and shifted the body's CSS properties to this one container. I'm not done yet with this part, since I need to fix the other element's design/layout, but this part is out of the way (for now, haha).

Here's the updated HTML and CSS for now. The CSS has the div and body fixed up (I removed the unnecessary elements for this query):

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

.main-container {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
  display: block;
  font-family: "Gill Sans", sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  background: url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1519751138087-5bf79df62d5b?q=80&w=2070&auto=format&fit=crop&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D");
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.container {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 60vw;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

form {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 60vw;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <title>Survey Form</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles-form.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="main-container">
    <h1 id="title">Survey Form</h1>
    <p id="description">Tell us how your experience was like!</p>
    <form method="post" action="" id="survey-form">
      <fieldset>
        <label for="name-label">Name <input id="name-label" name="name" type="text" placeholder="Please enter your name"  required/></label>
        <label for="email-label">Email <input id="email-label" name="email" type="email" placeholder="Please enter your email"  required/></label>
        <label for="number-label">Age <input id="number-label" name="number" type="number" placeholder="Please enter your age" min="16" max="120" required/></label>
      </fieldset>
      <fieldset>
        <legend>Would you recommend the event to a friend? (required)</legend>
        <select id="dropdown">
          <option value="">(select an option)</option>
          <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
          <option value="No">No</option>
        </select>
      </fieldset>
      <fieldset>
        <legend>Ticket Type (required)</legend>
        <label for="normal-ticket"><input id="normal-ticket" value="normal-ticket" name="ticket-type" type="radio" checked /> Normal</label>
        <label for="vip-ticket"><input id="vip-ticket" name="ticket-type" value="vip-ticket" type="radio" /> VIP Pass</label>
      </fieldset>
      <fieldset>
        <legend>What did you purchase?</legend>
        <label for="snacks">
          <input id="snacks" type="checkbox" value="snacks">
          Snacks
        </label>
        <label for="drinks-alcoholic">
          <input id="drinks-alcoholic" type="checkbox" value="drinks-alcoholic">
          Drinks (alcoholic)
        </label>
        <label for="drinks-non-alcoholic">
          <input id="drinks-non-alcoholic" type="checkbox" value="drinks-non-alcholic">
          Drinks (non-alcoholic)
        </label>
        <label for="food">
          <input id="food" type="checkbox" value="food">
          Food
        </label>
        <label for="merch">
          <input id="merch" type="checkbox" value="merch">
          Merchandise
        </label>
      </fieldset>
      <fieldset>
        <label>Any tips for next time? 
          <textarea name="tips"></textarea>
        </label>
      </fieldset>
      <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```